# How to describe a n-tuple of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

When I write computer programs, I often use something called a [*multidimensional array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type#Multi-dimensional_arrays). I think the concept would be equivalent to an **n-tuple of finite sequences**.

Suppose I have the following four sequences and 4-tuple called $t$:

$$A = (0)$$
$$B = (3,4,2)$$
$$C = (6,7,2,5)$$
$$D = (3,2)$$
$$t = (A, B, C, D)$$

I'm trying to determine how to describe the $Nth$ term of a sequence within the tuple. For example, in the C programming language -- where arrays start counting at the $0th$ term -- I would write `arr[3][1]` to describe the $2nd$ term of the $4th$ sequence in the multidimensional array `arr`.

What is the mathematical notation to describe the same term in a sequence in an n-tuple? Would it be $t_{(3)(1)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical notation is, frankly, whatever you decide to make it!  It is all about defining the notation you use, and making sure it doesn't collide with other notation.

For instance: you could have the elements (sets) of your tuple be $A^1,\ldots,A^n$, and let $A^i_j$ denote the $j$th element of $A_i$.

There are many other possibilities.  The most important thing is that, unless you are using a very standard notation, you explain what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you say what it represents, anything will do.

For elements of matrices, I've only seen $m_{i,j}$.

You can also use $a_i^j$ if you don't need to talk about powers of those elements.

There is also $f_i(j)$ which you should use if you're dealing with infinite sequence of infinite sequences. Thinking of it as a sequence of functions might help you find how to prove things about limits and such.